# Запятая и тире после длинного перечисления - как итог?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> И вот в то памятное утро, злющая как собака, открываю я гараж, который
>   снимала у соседа, залезаю в свою Ласточку, снимаю её со скорости
>   (владельцы автоматической коробки передач тут меня не поймут), и в
>   этот  самый неподходящий момент, потому что гараж забит всякой
>   ненужной ерундой этого соседа-Плюшкина, и осторожно там надо очень, –
>   звонит телефон.

Вот этот последний момент интересует:

*...и осторожно там надо очень, – звонит телефон.*

Чем можно оправдать тире?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тире можно оправдать необходимостью упорядочивания потока сознания в целом, но с ним в паре должно быть второе тире, после "момента" - только такой вставкой можно наладить связь "момента" с происходящим "в него" звонком телефона :) .

Comment: Ок, Саша, спасибо! Мне от обилия знаков не пришло в голову, как создать их симметрию... А оказалось - вставная конструкция в двух тире!